# Integrability of the composition of a function with the integer part function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am wondering if the function
\begin{align*}
 f(x)= \left\{
 \begin{array}{lr}
 \lfloor\sin(\dfrac{1}{x})\rfloor &  x\neq 0 \\
 0\quad & x=0
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{align*}
is integrable on [0,1]?

I guess it is integrable by the countability of discontinuities. However, I can't prove or disprove.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. We can safely exclude the countably many singleton points, where $f(x)=1$. Then $f$ is constant $-1$ or $0$ on countably many intervals, so we can split the integral over those. Note that this is fine because $f$ is almost always negative, so we do not get $\infty-\infty$.

According to wolframalpha, $\int_{-1}^0 f(x)dx=\frac{\log 2}{ \pi}-1$, for example. Interestingly, it seems that maple gives the value $\infty$ to the same integral, which is *definitely* wrong...

Another way to think about it, is that $f(x)$ is essentially $-\mathbb 1_{\{\sin\frac1x<0\}}$. $\sin$ and $\frac1x$ are measurable functions, so $\{\sin\frac1x<0\}$ is a measurable set, so the indicator function is integrable.

EDIT:

I’ll work it out on $[0,1]$. For $x>0$, $\sin\frac1x<0$ if and only if $x\in(\frac{1}{(2k-1)\pi},\frac{1}{2k\pi})$ for some $k\ge 1$. Let $\tilde f(x):=\min(f(x),0)$; this only changes the value on countably many points. Then
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx
= \int_0^1\tilde f(x)dx
= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1\pi\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)
= -\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}
= -\frac{\log2}{\pi}
$$
where we used the sum of the alternating harmonic series.

NOTE:
As mathcounterexamples.net has pointed out, integrable usually means that $\int |f(x)|dx<\infty$. Therefore, some of my above statements are wrong. Furthermore, I was thinking about the Lebesgue integral. What I should have said is that the function is Lebesgue integrable on any bounded interval, and that the Lebesgue integral is well-defined but $-\infty$ on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You seem to say that the indicator function $\chi_A$ of a measurable set $A$ is integrable. This is not true. $\mathbb R$ is measurable, but $\int \chi_{\mathbb R} = \infty$.

Comment: Right. I just meant that the integral is well-defined, not that it is finite.

Comment: Yes. Integrable usually means that the integral is finite.

Comment: You should also precise if you deal with Riemann or Lebesgue integral. Because a function $g$ that differs from a Riemann integrable map $f$ for *only countable points* may not be integrable.

Answer (score 1):

**We can see that $f$ is bounded**. *After that, it would be interesting to precise which interval you consider for the integration*. Let's consider two of those.

**First consider the interval $ I=[0,1]$.**

$f$ is a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) on each compact interval $[a,1] \subseteq [0,1]$ with $0<a<1$. Hence $f$ is Riemann-integrable. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111216/prove-for-bounded-f-if-fa-r-to-mathbbr-is-riemann-integrable-for-r) for a proof.

**Second, $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$**

Clear considering $\inf(0,f)$ : $\int_{\mathbb R} \inf(0,f) = - \infty$.

Comment: However, the Lebesgue integral is at least well defined.

Comment: @Milten No. For $x < -1/\pi$, you have $1/x \in (-\pi , 0)$ hence $f(x) = -1$. So the integral is not finite on $(-\infty, -1/\pi)$.

Comment: I agree that it is $-\infty$.